# Obj-C SimplePing Loop

Tags: objective-c, ping

Obj-C SimplePing LoopI am trying to loop through my whole LAN Network and ping any IP  possible to see where Devices are connected, a kind of Network Scanner, using Apples SimplePing example for OS X i figured out how to send a Ping to an IP, but somehow this doesn't work when you try to loop this doesn't work, it fires just the first time, than it stops...

after playing around with it, i saw 2 Pings to the first 2 Loops, but than it always stops...

what am i doing wrong?

My Code looks like this so far, simplified:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    // Insert code here to initialize your application
    x = 0;
    foundDevices = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    self.pinger = [[SimplePing alloc] init];
    [self startPinging];
}

-(void) startPinging{
    x = x +1;
    if(x < 256){
    NSString *hostName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"192.168.1.%i",x];
    self.pinger = [SimplePing simplePingWithHostName:hostName];
    self.pinger.delegate = (id)self;
    [self.pinger start];
    }
}
- (void)sendPing{
    [self.pinger sendPingWithData:nil];
}
- (void)simplePing:(SimplePing *)pinger didStartWithAddress:(NSData *)address{
    [self sendPing];
}
- (void)simplePing:(SimplePing *)pinger didReceivePingResponsePacket:(NSData *)packet{
    NSLog(@"%lu", (unsigned long)packet.length) ;
    [self.pinger stop];
    [self startPinging];
}
```

So i send just ONE Pind to each IP, wait for answer and Loop to prevent everything on the same three...

But this all doesn't work...

Plz help me

Answer (score 1):

SimplePing is scheduled on the main runloop, so you need to run the loop while you are expecting the ping to work.  To do this, after each call to [self.pinger start], insert code similar to this:

```
do {
    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate distantFuture]];
} while (self.pinger != nil);
```

After you receive the last ping you are expecting, set self.pinger to nil to break out of the do-while loop.  (You could optionally use a different flag to accomplish the same loop break, but this is how the main.m file in the SimplePing project works.)